# No `--architecture` option for tensorflow retrain?

Tags: tensorflow

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-122:~/src/tensorflow$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain   --help
usage: retrain.py [-h] [--image_dir IMAGE_DIR] [--output_graph OUTPUT_GRAPH]
                  [--output_labels OUTPUT_LABELS]
                  [--summaries_dir SUMMARIES_DIR]
                  [--how_many_training_steps HOW_MANY_TRAINING_STEPS]
                  [--learning_rate LEARNING_RATE]
                  [--testing_percentage TESTING_PERCENTAGE]
                  [--validation_percentage VALIDATION_PERCENTAGE]
                  [--eval_step_interval EVAL_STEP_INTERVAL]
                  [--train_batch_size TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE]
                  [--test_batch_size TEST_BATCH_SIZE]
                  [--validation_batch_size VALIDATION_BATCH_SIZE]
                  [--print_misclassified_test_images] [--model_dir MODEL_DIR]
                  [--bottleneck_dir BOTTLENECK_DIR]
                  [--final_tensor_name FINAL_TENSOR_NAME] [--flip_left_right]
                  [--random_crop RANDOM_CROP] [--random_scale RANDOM_SCALE]
                  [--random_brightness RANDOM_BRIGHTNESS]
```

Looks like there is no `--architecture` option available. If you pass it, the script will just ignore it without complaining. This means inception is the only option for retraining. Is it intended here?

Here is how I built the script:

```
/usr/local/bin/bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
```

Bazel version:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-122:~/src/tensorflow$ /usr/local/bin/bazel version
............................
Build label: 0.5.2
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Tue Jun 27 13:27:03 2017 (1498570023)
Build timestamp: 1498570023
Build timestamp as int: 1498570023
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this doubt still exists, however, if it still does: In the new version of tensorflow (version 1.7.0), the team have introduced "--tfhub_module" as an argument which is now used to control the architecture you want to use for retraining your model. With this argument, many new architectures like NASnet and PNASnet have been introduced. You can find the original code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py).